# I can`t make work my query having 2 fields set as primary key in a relational model in mysql + php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Im trying to code a register to events for a user. 

Im coding in php.
 It must shown all the events that the user is registered and all the events that the user is not registered.

This are the primary keys in the tables.:

`USUARIO        USUARIO_EVENTO   EVENTO 
idlogin_user    idlogin_user    cod_event
                cod_event`

It takes the id of idlogin_user from a cookie variable called 
$userlogueado

The thing that is actually happening is that is assuming that I have only one user as like idlogin_user is always the same even though is not always the same idlogin_user logued.

 I already tryed with UNION and JOIN and other sentences but none of them work.
And Im using this two querys :

```
 $query  = mysql_query (
                "select distinct 
                 evento.cod_event, 
                 evento.comienzo,
                 evento.fin,
                 evento.coste,
                 evento.nombre_event 
                 from evento 
                 WHERE (evento.cod_event not in (select distinct usuario_evento.cod_event from usuario_evento))");
$query2  = mysql_query ("select evento.cod_event, 
                    evento.comienzo,
                    evento.fin,
                    evento.coste,
                    evento.nombre_event 
                    from evento 
                    INNER JOIN usuario_evento
                    WHERE (evento.cod_event = usuario_evento.cod_event) 

                    UNION
                    (select * from usuario_evento where idlogin_user = $userlogueado)

                     ");
```

Comment: I don't quite understand this sentence: "The thing that is actually happening is that is assuming that I have only one user as like idlogin_user is always the same even though is not always the same idlogin_user logued." Could you please try to rephrase that and explain a bit more clearly?

Comment: If one of the users is registered to one of the events. Then when another user wants to registered to the same event, it showns like if he was already registered.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is create two separate queries for event which user signed up for and those which not.

Assuming user_events is many to many mapping table and user can register for event only once

```
SELECT * FROM user_events where user_id = '123';
```

Then select events which user is not registered and group by user id because there will be many users that are registered for that event.

```
SELECT * FROM user_events where event_id NOT IN(
    SELECT event_id FROM user_events where user_id = '123'
) GROUP BY event_id
```

Comment: Then i would need to make 2 querys for the ones that the user is registered and 2 querys for the ones that user is registered?

So i`ll have to make 4 querys? that seems to be impractical.

I want to do it in 2 querys. 

Maybe I didn't explain myself quite well. 

user_id is always the same in the page so why would group by user id?.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT cod_event, idlogin_user, 1 AS participance
FROM EVENTO 
JOIN USUARIO_EVENTO ON EVENTO.cod_event = USUARIO_EVENTO.cod_event
JOIN USUARIO ON USUARIO_EVENTO.idlogin_user = USUARIO.idlogin_user

UNION

SELECT outerEvento.cod_event, outerUsuario.idlogin_user, 0 AS participance
FROM EVENTO outerEvento
CROSS JOIN USUARIO outerUsuario
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT cod_event, idlogin_user
    FROM EVENTO innerEvento
    JOIN USUARIO_EVENTO innerUsuarioEvento ON innerEvento.cod_event = innerUsuarioEvento.cod_event
    JOIN USUARIO innerUsuario ON innerUsuarioEvento.idlogin_user = innerUsuario.idlogin_user
    WHERE outerEvento.cod_event = innerEvento.cod_event AND outerUsuario.idlogin_user = innerUsuario.idlogin_user
)
```

The column *participance* shows if a user participates (1) or not (0)

Comment: So... i should replace query 1 or query 2 with that code? O make a new query?

Comment: You can split it up the way you need it. It's just to show you how to retrieve the information you need. First part of query: *All Users with the events they are participating in*, Second part of query: *All Users with the events they are not participating in*

Comment: Thanks schlonzo ! I already solved it out ! I change the 2 querys and now they work